# Expected number of times two Poisson process events occur on the same day

Tags: poisson-process

So I have set up a Poisson Process N(t) with parameter L (events/year). I want to find the expected number of times over a 3 year period that 2 events occur on the same day.
My approach:

> First find $$P(N(1)=2) = (1/2)\times(L/360)^2\times\exp(-L/360) = p$$
>
> Second, treat the occurrence of $2$ events on the same day as a Bernoulli r.v., so $$E = p\times360\times3$$

Is my approach valid?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).
Thanks for explaining your approach.